# Define a string as a static resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

IS there a way to define a constant string to be used as a static resource across the whole application?

I am running a Wpf application but there is no main xaml form. The application is a collection of xaml controls handled by a single classic .cs form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a resource dictionary XAML file, let's say it's named `Dictionary.xaml` (Visual Studio can create you one automatically)

Then, add your static resource in this dictionary.

To finish, reference the dictionary in all your XAML controls:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: It works nicely although it can be a bit cumbersome if you have a lot of contols

Comment: I think that even if you have a lot of controls, it won't be that heavy: it's three lines to add for each control of your solution, and it especially helps you to understand your code more easily (as an example I have many different dictionaries in my solution: one for converters, one for templates, one for animations... Helps me getting to what I want very easily). But of course if you've only one resource to keep shared, it will feel heavy

Answer (score 90):

You can define it as an application resource:

```
 <Application x:Class="xxxxxx"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <clr:String x:Key="MyConstString">My string</clr:String>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

Comment: We have different approaches there, I'd like to know if you have an opinion on mine as well? I usually put all my resources into separate dictionary files for more readability (putting all the stuff in Application.Resources may finish on an incredible messy code), but does that include a difference in performance?

Comment: @Damascus: maybe having a separate dictionary is a better approach. I don't think there is a sensible performance difference, but never tryied a comparison: may be is a tiny optimization to ignore.

Comment: this would be ideal but as i said i dont have an application.xaml only a collection of usercontols so this wouldnt work in my case

Comment: @Marcom ok, so probably the Damascus reply is the one for you

Comment: Note that you can use [`<x:Static Member="clr:String.Empty" />`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203996/how-to-declare-an-empty-string-in-xaml-resourcedictionary) to declare an empty string

Answer (score 15):

Supplemantary to the [answer by @FelicePollano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5661231/3195477) - for code indentation to work I put this as a separate 'answer'.

If you happen to have your original constant defined in a .cs-file you can avoid duplicating its value in `<Application.Resources>` by this:

```
<x:Static x:Key="MyConstString" Member="local:Constants.MyString" />
```

For the reference `local` above to work you need to include the namespace  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Utils"` in the tag `<Application>`.

The cs-class could then look like this:

```
namespace Utils 
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public const string MyString = "My string";
    }
}
```

An example on usage in the xaml-code could then be:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource MyConstString}" />
```

Comment: I like this the best. It allows a single definition for a string that can be consumed from both XAML and C#, without the XAML needing to know about the code (outside the resource definition).

Comment: Double quotes are missing. <x:Static x:Key="MyConstString" Member="local:Constants.MyString" />

Comment: With this, I get this error: `An object of the type "System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.String"`. Does this solution really work?

Answer (score 5):

You can use like this:

First, sample constant variable:

```
namespace Constants
{
    public class ControlNames
    {
        public const string WrapperGridName = "WrapperGrid";
    }
}
```

And second XAML using:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Member=Constants:ControlNames.WrapperGridName}"
```