# How to declare an empty string in XAML ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, string

I have a `ResourceDictionary` that contains strings:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="Foo">Hello world</sys:String>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This dictionary is part of a theme, and in some themes, some of the strings are empty:

```
    <sys:String x:Key="Foo"></sys:String>
```

The trouble is that in that case, I get a `XamlParseException`:

> Cannot create object of type 'System.String'. CreateInstance failed,
>   which can be caused by not having a public default constructor for
>   'System.String'

I know it is possible to declare an empty string in an array resource, using `<x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />`, but I don't want an array... Using `x:Static` directly as the resource returns the markup extension, not the string. Putting `x:Static` in the `sys:String` element gives the same error as before.

Is it even possible to declare an empty string as an XAML resource? How?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Declaring it using `x:Static` seems to work just fine for me...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <x:Static x:Key="empty" Member="sys:String.Empty" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```cs
 cc.Content = (string)FindResource("empty"); //Casts to string without exception
```

Comment: You're right... I probably messed up somewhere when I tried. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work in Xaml though.. if you try something like `<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Foo}"/>` you get an error saying **An object of the type StaticExtension cannot be applied to a property that expects the type System.String**

Comment: Hmm, the designer was giving that error. Tried a rebuild and the error disappeared. Changing the Key, build, changing it back and build makes the error come back and after the next build it's gone again. Just a designer error it seems.. +1

Comment: @Meleak: That's one of the reasons why i open all XAML files in the Source Code Editor (the others being that the designer is slow and that i do not use it anyway)...

Comment: @H.B. - It works fine in .NET4.0 but not in .Net3.5. I looked it using converter. For 4.0 in converter, value is empty string but in case of 3.5, value is an object of `StaticExtension`. How to do it for 3.5? Any idea?