# XAML static string array with empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I have a combo box in my WPF application with a static item source (HTTP methods)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="methodsComboBox" Width="120"
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Methods}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Object.Method, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The static resource is a string array and looks like this:

```
<x:Array x:Key="Methods" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <sys:String>GET</sys:String>
    <sys:String>POST</sys:String>
    <sys:String>OPTIONS</sys:String>
    <sys:String>PUT</sys:String>
    <sys:String>DELETE</sys:String>
    <sys:String>HEAD</sys:String>
    <sys:String>TRACE</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

How can I put an empty string inside so I will have a default value for my combo box? Something like this:

```
<sys:String> </sys:String>
```

When I do this, I get a runtime error (`NullArgumentException`).

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7204178/616304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />
```

Comment: Visual Studio made it look like i have a compilation error (marked it with blue underline) but after rebuild it worked perfectly. Thank you!